# Python using 'with' to delete a file after use

Tags: python

I am using an explicitly named file as a temporary file. In order to make sure I delete the file correctly I've had to create a wrapper class for open().

This seems to work but

A] is it safe?

B] is there a better way?

```
import os

string1 = """1. text line
2. text line
3. text line
4. text line
5. text line
"""
class tempOpen():
    def __init__(self, _stringArg1, _stringArg2):
        self.arg1=_stringArg1
        self.arg2=_stringArg2

    def __enter__(self):
        self.f= open(self.arg1, self.arg2)
        return self.f

    def __exit__(self, exc_type=None, exc_val=None, exc_tb=None):
        self.f.close()
        os.remove(self.arg1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with tempOpen('tempfile.txt', 'w+') as fileHandel:
        fileHandel.write(string1)
        fileHandel.seek(0)
        c = fileHandel.readlines()
        print c
```

FYI: I cant use tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile for a lot of reasons

Comment: You might want to check for `self.f is None` in your `__exit__`.

Comment: Please elaborate on your "lot of reasons" why you can't use NamedTemporaryFile.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use the builtin [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module?

Comment: (And if you must write your own code, give your variables better names than `arg1`. They're a filename and a mode, so call them something that suggests that.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you can do a bit simpler with `contextlib.contextmanager`:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tempOpen( path, mode ):
    # if this fails there is nothing left to do anyways
    file = open(path, mode)

    try:
        yield file
    finally:
        file.close()
        os.remove(path)
```

There are two kinds of errors you want to handle differently: Errors creating the file and errors writing to it.